# xaml x:static cannot find namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resourcefile (named `StringResources`) in the Project `xyz.mvvm.res`
(res is a folder).

```
<Window x:Class="xyz.MVVM.Views.ReadAllReportWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:xyz.MVVM.res;assembly=xyz.MVVM"
             Title="{x:Static resources:StringResources.Window_Title}" 
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get an error

> "The name "StringResources" is not available in the Namespace
>   "clr-namespace:xyz.MVVM.res;assembly=xyz.MVVM".

The resourcefile is set to public!
I´am despairing..

Edit:
StringResources.Designer.cs:

```
namespace xyz.MVVM.res {
    using System;

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class StringResources {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal StringResources() {
        }

        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("TimeRecordReader.MVVM.res.StringResources", typeof(StringResources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        public static string Window_Title {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Window_Title", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `StringResources` (include namespace and `Window_Title` - no need for other properties).  Does this project reference `xyz`, or is it the same project?

Comment: @CharlesMager I´ve added it above

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, it turns out I had to delete the cache.

-Save and close MS Visual Studio

-Go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache\

-Delete contents

-Open MS Visual Studio

Note: Put your Version number instead of 14.0

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="xyz.MVVM.Views.ReadAllReportWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:xyz.MVVM.res;assembly=xyz.MVVM"
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Title>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static resources:StringResources.Window_Title}"/>
    </Window.Title>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: "The Member "StringResources" cannot be found in the target type"

Comment: There was a mistake. Check my edit. I've tested it with resource file and it works for me.

Comment: Now I get an error: "Cannot resolve symbol "InitializeComponent()".. Some background information: I´ve changed UserControl into Window I think the error has something to do with this